# can create() act as an alternate to associate() in a one-to-one relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Suppose there are two classes,

```
1- User
2- Contact
```

They have a 1-1 relationship:

```
User ->hasOne(Contact)
Contact ->belongsTo(User)
```

Now as per Laravel 5.x docs, I am required to "associate" child to parent.

```
$contact = Contact::create($input);
$user = Auth::User();
$contact->user()->associate($user);
```

But I've seen codes doing the same "association" like the following:-

```
$user->contact()->create($input);
```

Assuming my understanding is correct that both of these will result in the same outcome. Then why is this not mentioned in Laravel Docs, it gets really confusing for a beginner to follow docs that are "all over the place" .

Secondly, if this is a hack, or a way around, what are the implications comparing the two.

Comment: it's the same ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the same, obviously sometimes depending on your app, the associate way is needed, but if you can go for the `$user->contact()->create($input);` as its shorter/cleaner.